# which symbols are shown as space in android log?

Tags: android

I want to make request to url, but i meet unexpected problem.
I have some `String url` and `text - "book shop"`
Then i combine them together:

```
url = url+text;
url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

However, the space is not replaced and i am getting error

```
11-20 20:26:30.961: E/AndroidRuntime(13947): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query.
```

Did i make an error or there are other special symbols, which looks like space in logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encode your URL properly using the URLEncoder

```
 url = url+text;
 url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Depending on the structure of the url you are using you may want to just do

```
 url = url + URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, this might help

```
public class testclass {
static String url = "www.example.com/";
static String text = "bookashop";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String urlnew = text.replaceAll("a", "%20");
    String urla = (url+urlnew);
    System.out.println(urla);
}
```